# I am not able to split the Raw column in this python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to separate Website from Raw column and make website as new column but I am not able to do it please help out with this snippet

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4ZIE.png)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("E:\InputFile.txt",delimiter = "#")
data.columns = ['Date','ID','Name','Raw','Val']
data[['Raw']] = data[['Raw']].str.split( "/" )
data.head()
```

Comment: can you post a sample txt file and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
data[['Raw', 'Flag']] = data['Raw'].str.rsplit( "/" , n=1, expand=True)
```